# JQuery backgroundposition only seems to work in one direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been experimenting with Javascript animations for the first time recently and have run into this problem on one of my projects.
The below jquery scrolls horizontally without a problem. However when I add a second value in an attempt to scroll vertically nothing happens, and no errors are thrown up.

```
    $( ".space_background" ).ready(function() {
  $( ".space_background" ).animate({
    backgroundPosition: "+=200px"
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
});
```

The below code is what I thought I would have to add to achieve the effect

```
$( ".space_background" ).ready(function() {
      $( ".space_background" ).animate({
        backgroundPosition: "+=200px 200px"
      }, 5000, function() {
      });
    });
```

I have also tried backgroundPositionX and backgroundPositionY, neither of which work.

Any help sorely appeciated

Answer (score 0):

To move background in vertical direction using jQuery

```
$( ".space_background" ).ready(function() {
  $( ".space_background" ).animate({
    backgroundPositionY: "+=200px"
  }, 5000, function() {
  });
});
```

Above code works for few browsers reason being jQuery can't animate background position properly as one need it to animate with two values. Above code is working for browsers that implemented the non-standard background-position-x and -y like Internet Explorer. So you need to use any plugins for this like following -

```
/**
 * @author Alexander Farkas
 * v. 1.02
 */
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fx.step,{
        backgroundPosition: function(fx) {
           if (fx.state === 0 && typeof fx.end == 'string') {
               var start = $.curCSS(fx.elem,'backgroundPosition');
               start = toArray(start);
               fx.start = [start[0],start[2]];
               var end = toArray(fx.end);
               fx.end = [end[0],end[2]];
               fx.unit = [end[1],end[3]];
        }
        var nowPosX = [];
        nowPosX[0] = ((fx.end[0] - fx.start[0]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[0] + fx.unit[0];
        nowPosX[1] = ((fx.end[1] - fx.start[1]) * fx.pos) + fx.start[1] + fx.unit[1];
        fx.elem.style.backgroundPosition = nowPosX[0]+' '+nowPosX[1];

       function toArray(strg){
           strg = strg.replace(/left|top/g,'0px');
           strg = strg.replace(/right|bottom/g,'100%');
           strg = strg.replace(/([0-9\.]+)(\s|\)|$)/g,"$1px$2");
           var res = strg.match(/(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)\s(-?[0-9\.]+)(px|\%|em|pt)/);
           return [parseFloat(res[1],10),res[2],parseFloat(res[3],10),res[4]];
       }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

or 
http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/jquery.bgpos.js

Now you can write following code to animate backgrond position using jQuery

```
 $( ".space_background" ).animate({backgroundPosition:"(-150px 0)"});
```

For more reference:
http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have already tried this exact code.
In fact to make certain, I copied and pasted your code which had no affect.
Yet if I simply remove the X or the Y I'm back to the original side scrolling.
So what the hell is going wrong!

Comment: I have just realised that it works in IE and Chrome. But does not seem to be working in FF. Is this a known issue?